# QRegularExpression - find match with captured length backwards

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt5, qregularexpression

I can find previous match with this, but what I can't do, is to capture the length of the matched string:

```
int pos = 0;

if((pos = text.lastIndexOf(QRegularExpression(pattern), cursorPosition - 1)) != -1))
    cout << "Match at position: " << pos << endl;
```

I can capture the length of the match with `QRegularExpressionMatch`, but I could not find any flag/option in the `QRegularExpression` nor `QRegularExpressionMatch` classes that would change the direction of the search. (I don't mean to reverse the pattern, but finding the first match before a certain position in a string.)

Example (I want to find not-even-regex `"hello"`):

```
    hello world hello
            ^
          start (somewhere in the middle)
```

And this should be the matched section:

```
   hello world hello
   ^   ^
start  end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question? Your question doesn't make sense. `QString::lastIndexOf(QRegExp, int from)` does exactly what you're asking, which you already state is your answer. You also state that you want to get the length of the string, and then immediately state that that's all you can do.

Comment: Also, why are you running a search of a string using itself as the pattern? Very strange indeed.

Comment: @Phlucious 2. - Sorry, error while renaming. 1. - I want to get the length of the match, **the length of the match**, not just an offset.

Comment: Ah, after reading the description of QRegularExpression I realized what you were asking. Looks like a design oversight on Digia's part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in Qt5 [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html) != [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details) and I'm much more familiar with QRegExp. That said, I can't see a way to do what you want with QRegularExpression or QRegularExpression::match().

I would instead use [QString::indexOf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#indexOf-7) to search forwards and [QString::lastIndexOf](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#lastIndexOf-7) to search backwards. You can do this with either QRegExp or QRegularExpression if you just want to find the offset.

For example,

```
int pos = 8;
QString text = "hello world hello";
QRegularExpression exp("hello");

int bwd = text.lastIndexOf(exp, pos);   //bwd = 0
int fwd = text.indexOf(exp, pos);       //fwd = 12

//"hello world hello"
// ^       ^   ^
//bwd     pos fwd
```

You, however, also want to use the captured text, not just know where it is. This is where QRegularExpression seems to fail. As far as I can tell, there is no lastMatch() to retrieve the matched string after calling QString::lastIndexOf() QRegularExpress.

If you use a QRegExp instead, however, you can do this:

```
int pos = 8;
QString text = "hello world hello";
QRegExp exp("hello");

int bwd = text.lastIndexOf(exp, pos);   //bwd = 0
int fwd = text.indexOf(exp, pos);       //fwd = 12

//"hello world hello"
// ^       ^   ^
//bwd     pos fwd

int length = exp.cap(0).size();     //6... exp.cap(0) == "hello"
//or, alternatively
length = exp.matchedLength();       //6
```

The QRegExp object that you pass to the QString method gets updated with the captured string(s), which you can then use and manipulate. I can't imagine that they forgot to do that with QRegularExpression, but it looks like they might have.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I didn't know much of `QRegExp` but that it's inferior to `QRegularExpression`. I've realized I need to support lookbehind - isn't there really some way to do that with `QRegularExpression`?

Comment: From the docs: http://pcre.org/pcre.txt. Do a search for lookbehind assertions. Or here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind

Comment: Since Qt 5.5 there is oveload `int QString::lastIndexOf(const QRegularExpression &re, int from, QRegularExpressionMatch *rmatch) const` which allows capturing the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with QRegularExpression. Just use method

`QRegularExpressionMatch QRegularExpression::match(const QString &subject, int offset = 0, MatchType matchType = NormalMatch, MatchOptions matchOptions = NoMatchOption) const`

and later call methods `capturedLen(int)`, `capturedStart(int)` and similar for the result.

Links:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#match

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html

Comment: This however does not reverse the direction of the search (as requested in the question). Well, you can find all occurrences and get the last one, but that is very inefficient.